# How to activate existing Python environment with R reticulate

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, rstudio, reticulate

I have the following existing Python environments:

```
$   conda info --envs

base                  *  /home/ubuntu/anaconda3
tensorflow2_latest_p37     /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_latest_p37
```

What I want to do is to activate `tensorflow2_latest_p37` environment
and use it in R code. I tried the following code:

```
library(reticulate)
use_condaenv( "tensorflow2_latest_p37")

library(tensorflow)
tf$constant("Hello Tensorflow!")
```

But it failed to recognize the environment:

```
> library(reticulate)
> use_condaenv( "tensorflow2_latest_p37")
/tmp/RtmpAs9fYG/file41912f80e49f.sh: 3: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_latest_p37/etc/conda/activate.d/00_activate.sh: Bad substitution
Error in Sys.setenv(PATH = new_path) : wrong length for argument
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(Sys.which("sh"), fi, stdout = if (identical(intern, FALSE)) "" else intern) :
  running command ''/bin/sh' /tmp/RtmpAs9fYG/file41912f80e49f.sh' had status 2
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: It's a reticulate bug. See [this](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/1155).

Comment: Where did you define `tf`?
Are you missing `tf = import("tensorflow")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the most reliable way is to set the `RETICULATE_PYTHON` system variable before running `library(reticulate)`, since this will load the default environment and changing environments seems to be a bit of an issue. So you should try something like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
py_bin <- reticulate::conda_list() %>% 
  filter(name == "tensorflow2_latest_p37") %>% 
  pull(python)

Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = py_bin)
library(reticulate)
```

You can make this permanent by placing this in an `.Renviron` file. I usually place one in the project folder, so it is evaluated upon opening the project. In code this would look like that:

```r
readr::write_lines(paste0("RETICULATE_PYTHON=", py_bin), 
                   ".Renviron", append = TRUE)
```

Or even easier, use `usethis::edit_r_environ(scope = "project")` (thank you @rodrigo-zepeda!).

Comment: Instead of the `writeLines` a more friendly option might be to `usethis::edit_r_profile()` and edit by hand. Or `readr::write_lines` with `append = TRUE`

Comment: Neat! I was not aware that `readr::write_lines` had an append option (I changed the answer). I would not use `usethis::edit_r_profile()` here, since it opens your default `.Rprofile` file in your home directory and I would say setting the `RETICULATE_PYTHON` variable on a project basis makes more sense.

Comment: @JBGruver `usethis::edit_r_profile(scope = "project")` opens the project's R profile while `usethis::edit_r_profile(scope = "user")` opens the user's

Comment: Wow, I probably should have checked that!